# Computational cost of finding only the eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matlab, numerical-linear-algebra

I have read that the computational cost of full eigendecomposition (finding both eigenvalues and eigenvectors) is $O(n^3)$. But what is the cost if we want to find only eigenvalues?

How does MATLAB function `eig` work? Does the time depend on whether you ask only for the eigenvalues or also for the eigenvectors?

Comment: The naive way of finding the characteristic polynomial through the recursive determinant algorithm is $o(n!)$. So that's presumably _not_ how it's done.

Comment: Same. Finding eigenvectors once the eigenvalues are known amounts to solving at most $n$ linear $n\times n$ systems. The optimal complexity of the latter is $n^2$, so the total is $O(n^3)$. For the eigenvalues only the best known runtime is $O(n^3+n^2\log^2 n\log b)$, see [CS SE](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/2810), so ditching eigenvectors does not alter the order of growth. What MATLAB does [depends on a version](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/18460-different-precision-of-eig-in-matlab-7-1-and-matlab-7-9), and is unlikely to be optimal.

Comment: @Conifold That is not CS SE, that is TCS SE.

Comment: The specific subroutines can be found at the Netlib.  http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d2/d8a/group__double_s_yeigen.html

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, we search approximations of eigen-values (-vectors) with a fixed number of significand digits. In these conditions, we assume that our real matrix $A$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbb{C}$ by a change of basis of matrix $P$.

The complexities are $\approx 15n^3$ for the eigenvalues and $\approx 40n^3$ for values-vectors. Of course, the direct calculation is not stable when the condition number of $P$ is bad. Thus, in general, the standard algorithm uses a small number of iterations (2  or 3 in general for each eigenvalue).

Of course, when the matrix is symmetric, there is no problem with $P$ and the algorithm is in general stable. We can divide the above complexities by 2 for these matrices.